# TCP/IP fast data logger

Tags: tcpclient, fpga, ethernet, tcp

I want to implement a fast DAQ (10Mbit/s) system for capturing data from an array of sensors. So far I have implemented my system based on Wiznet W5300 and an FPGA and I am able to communicate through TCP/IP with my computer. FPGA working as server and PC as a client and I am using only one socket on port 5000. So far Ive tested various applications for capturing and saving the data on Windows with no success (some of them are crashing and some of them are lack in terms of speed). As I am not an expert on Network programming what would be the best way to capture and save the data on PC side as fast and reliable as possible? I am always aiming for something simple. Any type of guidance would be welcomed.

Comment: While I was working on a project, we were using GNU Radio, and one of the major parts on the design was capturing a large amount of data via ethernet. You can find the source of both the FPGA and the Linux (PC) software on their GIT repository!

Comment: Can you please send me the link?

Comment: You have the main repository here: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio and you have the info about the whole tool chain here: https://kb.ettus.com/Building_and_Installing_the_USRP_Open-Source_Toolchain_(UHD_and_GNU_Radio)_on_Linux

Answer (score 0):

I am using tcpdump and very happy with it in linux and know that there is a Windows equivalent of it called windump. Here is the url for it :

http://www.winpcap.org/windump/

Comment: I suppose Windump works like Wireshark. Ive also tried to capture the data with Wireshark but the speed problems come from client, so Windump will copy anything the client asks for. Is there a way to use Windump as a standalone client and capture the data or use any other tcpclient programm with storing data capabilities?

Comment: Pcap must not be a big deal for you. Also tcpdump supports it via libpcap in linux. In windows its name is winpcap. Check its documentation and give a try for it.

Comment: Can you give me a short intro to that cause is kind of hard for me to start with. Is there any Windows application that I can use instead without much configuration?

Comment: Here is a windows tutorial : http://www.zorranlabs.com/articles/tcpdump_for_windows.htm

Comment: First run windump -D to list interface and select it. In your case, to listen port 5000 it should be something like : windump -i1 -s 65535 -X tcp port 5000

Comment: But still how can I initiate the communication if there is no client programm?

Comment: You need to write them all from command line after installing windump. C:\> windump ...

Comment: The communication will not start if I dont initiate the communication with my client programm. Windump just listens it doesnt initiate the communication.

Comment: So why dont you just start it and then begin to listen comm?

Comment: I have some problems with the speed of the communication as I descricbed in the first post and I dont know if they are comming from the client programm or for the operating system, thats why I want to use a second method to see if I have any changes. My BW is at the moment about 3Mbit/s which is way to low for 100Mbit/ss or even 10Mbit/s. Things are getting worst if WIFI is also enabled on the same pc.